# setGlobalOptions({region: }); not changing the region

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am new to Firebase Cloud Functions.
After reading the documentation I tried to set a region in my index.ts like so:

```
import {setGlobalOptions} from "firebase-functions/v2/options";
...
setGlobalOptions({region: "europe-west3"});
...
```

And when I deploy the functions using

```
firebase deploy --only functions
```

I see the following:

```
i  functions: updating Node.js 18 (1st Gen) function initializeNewUser(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 18 (1st Gen) function validateFileSize(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 18 (1st Gen) function checkStorageSpace(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 18 (1st Gen) function onFileDeleted(us-central1)...
```

Can somebody tell me why it was not set to the **europe-west3**?

Comment: Are the functions 1st gen or 2nd gen? Because `setGlobalOptions` only works for 2nd gen functions.

Comment: @MarkMunene ah, they are indeed 1st gen... My bad :D 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The solution turned out to be the following:

1. Cloud functions must be imported from **"firebase-functions/v2"**
2. Some functions (*i.e. functions.auth.user().onCreate* aren't implemented yet for 2nd gen functions. So you will have to use the 1st gen functions for those.